# How to code inlineable mutual abstracion in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inline, abstraction

Example first:

```
template <class HashingSolution> 
struct State : public HashingSolution {

  void Update(int idx, int val) {
    UpdateHash(idx, val);
  }

  int GetState(int idx) {
    return ...;
  }
};

struct DummyHashingSolution {
  void UpdateHash(int idx, int val) {}
  void RecalcHash() {}
};

struct MyHashingSolution {
  void UpdateHash(int idx, int val) {
    ...
  }

  void RecalcHash() {
    ...
    UpdateHash(idx, GetState(idx)); // Problem: no acces to GetState function, can't do recursive application of templates
    ...
  }
};
```

In this example I can pass MyHashingSolution to State class so State have access to HashingSolution's methods, but HashingSolution can't call GetState. Is it possible to work around this?

This is in the deepest loop. virtual function here drops the performance by more than 25%.
Inlineing is crucial for me.

Comment: Post some code. What do you mean by combinations? Why is this community wiki?`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem either. It seems like the CRTP idiom may solve your problem, but without some sample code of what you're trying to do, I can't be sure.

Comment: And why is inlining the crucial thing?  If the performance requirements are so strict that micro-optimization is necessary from design onward, you probably shouldn't come with a partial design and ask us to twist it.

Comment: Not to mention, what's a "mutual (but not recursive)" call?  Is there anything you're not telling us that makes just writing all the functions for the combinations explicitly?  Templates might help, but without knowing what you're trying to do I can't be more specific.

Comment: This is bordering on not being a question!

Comment: Just on the borderline, I'd say.  I seriously considered voting to close.  I certainly wouldn't vote to reopen.

Comment: I'm just editing it. Please wait.

Comment: Thanks. Should I undo community wiki? I don't really know when should I use it.

Comment: Community wiki is usually for "fluff" questions like polls. They don't generate reputation for up/down votes. See more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow/128436#128436

Comment: This question seem to have a "bad fame" and might be not answered at all. Can I repost it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As jalf suggests in the comments, you probably want to use a variant of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) (CRTP).  That is, make `MyHashingSolution` a class template parametrised by the derived class:

```
template <typename D>
struct MyHashingSolution {
    typedef D Derived;

    void UpdateHash(int idx, int val) {
        ...
    }

    void RecalcHash() {
        ...
        UpdateHash(idx, derived().GetState(idx));
        ...
    }

private:
    // Just for convenience
    Derived& derived() { return *static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};
```

In this case, because you want the derived `State` class to also be a template, you need to take the slightly unusual step of declaring `State` as a class template that takes a *template template parameter*:

```
template <template <class T> class HashingSolution>
struct State : public HashingSolution<State<HashingSolution> > {
typedef HashingSolution<State<HashingSolution> > Parent;

    void Update(int idx, int val) {
        Parent::UpdateHash(idx, val);   // g++ requires "Parent::"
    }

    int GetState(int idx) {
        return ...;
    }
};
```

The key point is that, provided `State` inherits from `HashingSolution<State<HashingSolution> >`, `Derived` is a derived class of `HashingSolution<State<HashingSolution> >` so the `static_cast<Derived*>(this)` downcast in `HashingSolution<State>::derived()` compiles and works correctly.  (If you mess up and derive `State` from `HashingSolution<SomeOtherType>` instead and then try something that involves a call to `derived()`, the compiler will complain as the requirements for `static_cast<>` are not met.)

Then declare the concrete `State` class you want to use like so:

```
typedef State<MyHashingSolution> MyState;
```

Unfortunately this solution has the side effect that you will need to change `DummyHashingSolution` (and any other such types) to templates that ignore their one template argument, in order to make them usable as template template arguments.

Comment: The parent doesn't *have* to be parametrised. Although it's almost certainly better that way from a coupling standpoint.

Comment: @Cache: Well, I assumed from the sample code that this was an important feature to the asker. (I myself would probably just make State a concrete class and use a typedef to control which HashingSolution was used, as it's unlikely you need >1 State types in a given program.)

Comment: Actually I need many States for simulation purposes. For different simulations I need differen but similar implementations.

stati_cast was the key.

Answer (score 0):

As a shot in the dark, considering the almost complete lack of information in the question (see comments):  would templates be useful?  They're often good for compile-time polymorphism.

To get any more potentially useful information, please explain the problem more.  Look at the problem comments.  Tell us why you know what micro-optimizations need to be made when you're still working on fundamental design.  If there's anything non-mainstream about the compilation or execution environments, give us a few details.